# How to instance an UserControl each time an item is added to an ObservableCollection in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have an ObservableCollection of items of class X. I have a user control to show to the user the information inside X. How can I create the binding so the user controls are created when data is added to the ObservableCollection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use and [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) with an [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) containging the `UserControl`. Bind or set the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx#Y6) to your collection.

See [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for examples and in-depth explanaitions.

Comment: Mmmm, I'm not an expert on WPF. Can you elavorate the answer just a bit more to get me on track?

Comment: @SoMoS: The ItemTemplate is a DataTemplate which contains what should be created for each item in the ItemsSource, the DataContext inside the template is the data-item which is being templated. See the reference link i added.